# Possible to retrieve IDENTITY column value on insert using SqlCommandBuilder (without using Stored Proc)?

Tags: .net, ado.net

FYI: I am running on dotnet 3.5 SP1

I am trying to retrieve the value of an identity column into my dataset after performing an update (using a SqlDataAdapter and SqlCommandBuilder).
After performing SqlDataAdapter.Update(myDataset), I want to be able to read the auto-assigned value of `myDataset.tables(0).Rows(0)("ID")`, but it is System.DBNull (despite the fact that the row was inserted).

(Note: I do not want to explicitly write a new stored procedure to do this!)

One method often posted http://forums.asp.net/t/951025.aspx modifies the SqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand and UpdatedRowSource like so:

```
SqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText += "; SELECT MyTableID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord
```

Apparently, this seemed to work for many people in the past, but does not work for me.

Another technique: http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=619031&SiteID=1 doesn't work for me either, as after executing the SqlDataAdapter.Update, the SqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters collection is reset to the original (losing the additional added parameter).

Does anyone know the answer to this???

Comment: Just for the references: The Code Project article "[Using SCOPE_IDENTITY with CommandBuilder and DataAdapter](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/288850/Using-SCOPE-IDENTITY-with-CommandBuilder-and-DataA)" was the solution that helped me. (I'm _not_ the autor of the article).

Comment: I know this is old but in vs 2015 this is still very buggy. I had the same issue and already was using the code from the above article. For me the fix was to rename "set ID to SCOPE_IDENTITY()" to "SET SCOPE_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" Yes I know there is no real difference but now it works again for some reason

Answer (score 10):

This is a problem that I've run into before, the bug seems to be that when you call
da.Update(ds);
the parameters array of the insert command gets reset to the inital list that was created form your command builder, it removes your added output parameters for the identity.

The solution is to create a new dataAdapter and copy in the commands, then use this new one to do your da.update(ds);

like

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Top 0 " + GetTableSelectList(dt) + 
"FROM " + tableName,_sqlConnectString);
SqlCommandBuilder custCB = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
custCB.QuotePrefix = "[";
custCB.QuoteSuffix = "]";
da.TableMappings.Add("Table", dt.TableName);

da.UpdateCommand = custCB.GetUpdateCommand();
da.InsertCommand = custCB.GetInsertCommand();
da.DeleteCommand = custCB.GetDeleteCommand();

da.InsertCommand.CommandText = String.Concat(da.InsertCommand.CommandText, 
"; SELECT ",GetTableSelectList(dt)," From ", tableName, 
" where ",pKeyName,"=SCOPE_IDENTITY()");

SqlParameter identParam = new SqlParameter("@Identity", SqlDbType.BigInt, 0, pKeyName);
identParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(identParam);

da.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;

//new adaptor for performing the update                     
SqlDataAdapter daAutoNum = new SqlDataAdapter();
daAutoNum.DeleteCommand = da.DeleteCommand;
daAutoNum.InsertCommand = da.InsertCommand;
daAutoNum.UpdateCommand = da.UpdateCommand;

daAutoNum.Update(dt);
```

Comment: Thanks! This strange workaround works. So, the moral of the story, if you want to adjust the commands from the command builder to use in a data adapter, then create a seperate data adapter for the command builder. After comparing the internals of two commands which were 'exactly' the same, and the one worked while the other didn't, I saw that an internal IsDirty was still false for the command that didn't work.

Comment: The situation still exists in NET.Core 2.2. If the insert statement was generated thru a sqlCommandBuilder than manipulation of the SQL statement with string operations will be reverted after calling dataAdapter.Update(table/rows). 
This can be observed in sql-profiler and in debug mode by watching the CommandText Property.

Hint: if you want to retrieve more the one column from the db after the insert use OUTPUT INSERTED.* in the insert statement. This will return complete row.

Answer (score 4):

The insert command can be instructed to update the inserted record using either output parameters or the first returned record (or both) using the UpdatedRowSource property...

```
InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both;
```

If you wanted to use a stored procedure, you'd be done.  But you want to use a raw command (aka the output of the command builder), which doesn't allow for either a) output parameters or b) returning a record.  Why is this?  Well for a) this is what your InsertCommand will look like...

```
INSERT INTO [SomeTable] ([Name]) VALUES (@Name)
```

There's no way to enter an output parameter in the command. So what about b)?  Unfortunately, the DataAdapter executes the Insert command by calling the commands ExecuteNonQuery method.  This does not return any records, so there is no way for the adapter to update the inserted record.

So you need to either use a stored proc, or give up on using the DataAdapter.

Comment: "the DataAdapter executes the Insert command by calling the commands ExecuteNonQuery method".....i suppose that would explain the behavior I am seeing, but then how did other people get the example teqhniques I posted to work?  And what is the purpose of the UpdatedRowSource property???

Comment: All the examples I saw used stored procedures.  UpdatedRowSource works fine with stored procedures.  The one's that didn't use stored procedures were not using DataAdapters.

Answer (score 4):

What works for me is configuring a MissingSchemaAction:

```
SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
myDataAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
```

This lets me retrieve the primary key (if it is an identity, or autonumber) after an insert.

Good luck.

Comment: Works great, no messing with the commands. I wonder why I couldn't find this golden tip anywhere else? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer that works for me here: http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-ado-net/4933/Have-soln-but-need-understanding-return-IDENTITY-issue

Code that worked (from the site - attributed to Girish)

```
//_dataCommand is an instance of SqlDataAdapter
//connection is an instance of ConnectionProvider which has a property called DBConnection of type SqlConnection
//_dataTable is an instance of DataTable

SqlCommandBuilder bldr = new SqlCommandBuilder(_dataCommand);
SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(bldr.GetInsertCommand().CommandText, connection.DBConnection);
cmdInsert.CommandText += ";Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id";

SqlParameter[] aParams = new
SqlParameter[bldr.GetInsertCommand().Parameters.Count];
bldr.GetInsertCommand().Parameters.CopyTo(aParams, 0);
bldr.GetInsertCommand().Parameters.Clear();

for(int i=0 ; i < aParams.Length; i++)
{
 cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(aParams[i]);
}

_dataCommand.InsertCommand = cmdInsert;
_dataCommand.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;
_dataCommand.Update(_dataTable);
```

Comment: This worked! Just make sure to replace id in "Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id" with your table's key field name.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this works for me :

```
SqlDataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText += "; SELECT MyTableID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()" InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It was just solved when I cloned the command generated by the commandbuilder. It looks that even when you change the commandText of the insertcommand, it keeps getting the command generated by the Commandbuilder...
Here it's the code that I used to clone the command...

```
        private static void CloneBuilderCommand(System.Data.Common.DbCommand toClone,System.Data.Common.DbCommand repository)
    {
        repository.CommandText = toClone.CommandText;
        //Copying parameters
        if (toClone.Parameters.Count == 0) return;//No parameters to clone? go away!
        System.Data.Common.DbParameter[] parametersArray= new System.Data.Common.DbParameter[toClone.Parameters.Count];
        toClone.Parameters.CopyTo(parametersArray, 0);
        toClone.Parameters.Clear();//Removing association before link to the repository one
        repository.Parameters.AddRange(parametersArray);            
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to (a) insert one record into table, (b) use a DataSet, and (c) not use a stored procedure, then you can follow this:

1. Create your dataAdapter, but in the select statement add WHERE 1=0, so that you don't have to download the entire table - optional step for performance
2. Create a custom INSERT statement with scope identity select statement and an output parameter.
3. Do the normal processing, filling the dataset, adding the record and saving the table update.
4. Should now be able to extract the identity from the parameter directly.

Example:

```
    '-- post a new entry and return the column number
    ' get the table stucture
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(String.Concat("SELECT * FROM [", fileRegisterSchemaName, "].[", fileRegisterTableName, "] WHERE 1=0"), sqlConnectionString)
    Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

    ' since we want the identity column back (FileID), we need to write our own INSERT statement
    da.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(String.Concat("INSERT INTO [", fileRegisterSchemaName, "].[", fileRegisterTableName, "] (FileName, [User], [Date], [Table]) VALUES (@FileName, @User, @Date, @Table); SELECT @FileID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();"))
    da.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord
    With da.InsertCommand.Parameters
        .Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1024, "FileName")
        .Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 24, "User")
        .Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "Date")
        .Add("@Table", SqlDbType.VarChar, 128, "FileName")
        ' allow the @FileID to be returned back to us
        .Add("@FileID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "FileID")
        .Item("@FileID").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    End With

    ' copy the table structure from the server and create a reference to the table(dt)
    da.Fill(ds, fileRegisterTableName)
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(fileRegisterTableName)

    ' add a new record
    Dim dr As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
    dr("FileName") = fileName
    dr("User") = String.Concat(Environment.UserDomainName, "\", Environment.UserName)
    dr("Date") = DateTime.Now()
    dr("Table") = targetTableName
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)

    ' save the new record
    da.Update(dt)

    ' return the FileID (Identity)
    Return da.InsertCommand.Parameters("@FileID").Value
```

But thats pretty long winded to do the same thing as this...

```
' add the file record
    Dim sqlCmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(String.Concat("INSERT INTO [", fileRegisterSchemaName, "].[", fileRegisterTableName, "] (FileName, [User], [Date], [Table]) VALUES (@FileName, @User, @Date, @Table); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();"), New SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    With sqlCmd.Parameters
        .AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName)
        .AddWithValue("@User", String.Concat(Environment.UserDomainName, "\", Environment.UserName))
        .AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now())
        .AddWithValue("@Table", targetTableName)
    End With
    sqlCmd.Connection.Open()
    Return sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue for me was where the code was placed.

Add the code in the RowUpdating event handler, something like this:

```
void dataSet_RowUpdating(object sender, SqlRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
    {
        e.Command.CommandText += "; SELECT ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
        e.Command.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If those other methods didn't work for you, the .Net provided tools (SqlDataAdapter) etc. don't really offer much else regarding flexibility. You generally need to take it to the next level and start doing stuff manually. Stored procedure would be one way to keep using the SqlDataAdapter. Otherwise, you need to move to another data access tool as the .Net data libraries have limits since they design to be simple. If your model doesn't work with their vision, you have to roll your own code at some point/level.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using just a command object.

```vb
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
sb.Append(" Insert into ")
sb.Append(tbl)
sb.Append(" ")
sb.Append(cnames)
sb.Append(" values ")
sb.Append(cvals)
sb.Append(";Select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as id") 'add identity selection

Dim sql As String = sb.ToString

Dim cmd As System.Data.Common.DbCommand = connection.CreateCommand
cmd.Connection = connection
cmd.CommandText = sql
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord

'retrieve the new identity value, and update the object
Dim dec as decimal = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar, Decimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's even easier, no need in any custom commands. When you create tableadapter in dataset designer, specify "refresh the data table" in Advanced Options of the wizard. With that, after you issue dataadapter.update mydataset , you will find identify column in the datatable populated with the new value from the database.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Mytable;" , sqlConnection);

SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

da.DeleteCommand = (SqlCommand)cb.GetDeleteCommand().Clone();
da.UpdateCommand = (SqlCommand)cb.GetUpdateCommand().Clone();

SqlCommand insertCmd = (SqlCommand)cb.GetInsertCommand().Clone();

insertCmd.CommandText += ";SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();";
insertCmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
da.InsertCommand = insertCmd;
da.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;

cb.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the changes you made to the **InsertCommand** are not taken into consideration when using the ***SqlDataAdapter.Update(DataSet)*** Method.
the perfect solution is to clone the **InsertCommand** generated by the **CommandBuilder**.

```
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
cb.ConflictOption = ConflictOption.OverwriteChanges;

da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand().Clone();
da.InsertCommand.CommandText += "; SELECT idTable = SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
da.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;

da.Update(dt);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into using LINQ instead?  I understand this doesn't address your actual question, but if you are using .NET 3.5 you really ought to try using LINQ.  In fact, with the advent of Code First EntityFramework, I think you could easily choose either LINQ to SQL or EF as relatively lightweight alternatives to rolling your own DAL.