# C# Add identity column of a table to insert command

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I am stuck with a problem where i want to insert into a table which has an identity column. I am using command builder for this purpose. But when command builder builds the Insertion command, it does not contain the identity column in it(rest of the columns are there). I am forced to insert manually into identity column. How should I proceed to get identity column into my Insertion Command?

```
SqlDataAdapter da = null;
SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = null;
DataSet dsSourceTable = LoadData(query, SourceCn, ref da, "dsMigratedData", table, ref cmdBuilder);
da.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand();
da.InsertCommand.Connection = DestCn;
```

However I also used this

```
da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("AppointmentID", SqlDbType.Int));
```

and finally

```
 cmd = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Appointment ON", DestCn, transaction);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
foreach (DataRow row in dsSourceTable.Tables[table].Rows)
{
      foreach (SqlParameter p in da.InsertCommand.Parameters)
      {
             p.Value = row[p.SourceColumn];
      }
      da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Possible to retrieve IDENTITY column value on insert using SqlCommandBuilder (without using Stored Proc)?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136536/possible-to-retrieve-identity-column-value-on-insert-using-sqlcommandbuilder-wit

Comment: What happens when you use the original from the querybuilder? SQL should insert a new ID itself, that is what Identity Columns are there for.

Comment: Actually, I need to migrate some data from other but similar database. For that I need to add Identity myself as well. I have deleted the data from destination so that no duplicate is possible.

Comment: If this is a onetime import, see if you can use the backup / restore functions in Sql Studio. If not, create the Query by hand. I've read somewhere on MSDN that SqlcommandBuilder should not be used like this.

Comment: OK Stephan, I'll consider this. Thanks fr your support.

Comment: I am not sure it matters, but try adding "@" before Sql Parameters

Answer (score 3):

Clarification of the whys-and-wherefores of this question: 
This situation might better illustrate why you might need to do what is asked for:

Sync server data with an imbedded database (Sqlite). Push changes from client up to server and then download changes to client (upsert).

In this case, CommandBuilder needs to include the integer primary key from the SQL Server source table, which is BIGINT IDENTITY, and INT AUTOINCREMENT in Sqlite (in SQLite3, INTEGER ROWID columns are INT64, so SQL Server must be BIGINT to match).

Now, in Sqlite, you can specify the PK column on insert  and it takes it;, you don't have to do anything like SET IDENTITY_INSERT  ON. So you really just need the PK column in the insert command.

You can mash up something using the code above, but it would have been really much simpler to have CommandBuilder include the primary key somehow.

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/35994e90-b47d-4e52-8c5d-b7a3a51dd486) talks about manually hacking the InsertCommand.CommandText property, but that it too hack-ish, in my opinion.

There might be an issue calling da.Update(). A lower post in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136536/possible-to-retrieve-identity-column-value-on-insert-using-sqlcommandbuilder-wi) indicates ADO might wipe any manual parameter adding, and offers a solution by copying the dataadapter before calling Update(). Another thread tells the tale of whoa of someone running into this problem (no resolution on that thread though).

So, after much mucking around, I figured out this about Sqlite: If the table uses AUTOINCREMENT for the primary key, instead of allowing the default behavior for an integer primary key (automatically does a plus-one when no primary key column specified on insert), then you can't insert your own value for the primary key.

My ultimate solution, because I ran out of time, was to do what was described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/35994e90-b47d-4e52-8c5d-b7a3a51dd486), that is I removed AUTOINCREMENT from the local Sqlite database, hacked InsertCommand.CommandText and manually adding the primary key column as a regular parameter (not adding it as a primary key):

```
SQLiteCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder();
commandBuilder.DataAdapter = daLocal;
SQLiteCommand insertCommand = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
insertCommand.CommandText = insertCommand.CommandText.Replace("] (", "] ([id], ");
insertCommand.CommandText = insertCommand.CommandText.Replace("VALUES (", "VALUES (@id, ");
SQLiteParameter pkParam = new SQLiteParameter("id", DbType.Int64, "id");
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(pkParam);
daLocal.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
```

This gave the desired affect of inserting primary key values from the source SQL Server table into the local Sqlite table.

In the end I failed to find a property of either the DataTable object or the SQLiteDataAdapter object that I could manipulate that would cause either an explictly created SqliteCommandBuider or the builder baked into SQLiteDataAdapter create the id column and parameter for SQLiteDataAdapter.InsertCommand.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

database inserts Identity columns byitself...you dont have to include identty column value in your query.
If problems are coming try,take the value that your command builder is generating in runtime and execute it in database and see what exactly is happening
Make sure our query is in right sequence as in it matches the sequence of column in your table.

Comment: Thanks for your post Neelam, Actually my problem is to forcefully insert identity column entry through code.

Comment: thats what...you cant...sql wont allow you to...because thats what the identity columns are for...auto incrementing the value of the column.you have to specify all the values except identity...sql will take careof identity.

Comment: we can use IDENTITY_INSERT property to manually insert into identity. we just need to make it ON.