# Can we get the Inserted Record ID?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, dataset

I have a problem like retriving the Inserted Record Identity Value.Here I am inserting the record using DatSet.Suppose I have a table GAME where I have deleted all the records and I am inserting the record using dataset as given below

```
SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from GAME", sqlCon);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataRow dr;
            sqlAdapter.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, "GAME");
            sqlAdapter.Fill(ds, "GAME");
            dr = ds.Tables["GAME"].NewRow();
            SqlCommandBuilder objSqlcmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter);
            dr["NAME"] = "TABLE TENNIS";
            dr["PlayedDate"] = "01/02/2010";
            ds.Tables["GAME"].Rows.Add(dr);
            sqlAdapter.Update(ds, "GAME");
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(dr["GameId"]), "DataSet Demo");
```

Here always I am getting the GameId as '0'. But I Need to get the Inserted Record Identity Value.Is there any possible way to get using DataSet?I know the process to get inserted record Id value using @@Identity e.t.c.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136536/possible-to-retrieve-identity-column-value-on-insert-using-sqlcommandbuilder-wi looks like a very similar question, and there's a few different approaches to try there.

Comment: Actually how can we implement using C#?Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

Use [OUTPUT Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) e.g. Output.Inserted, Output.Updated , Output.Deleted. I could have done a small example for you but I found it is already there [[SQL SERVER – 2005 – OUTPUT Clause Example and Explanation with INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE]](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/) . Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Actually how can we implement using C#?Can you please elaborate more?