# how to get autoincrement id after tableAdapter.update vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, data-binding

I am using compactSQL.

I am able to make commit changes but don't know how to get the autoincrement id inserted in table.

```
  Dim row As Integer = CustomerTableAdapter.Update(ArfDynamicsDataSet.Customer)
```

the row shows number of rows added in db but how can i get the newly added autoincement id.

Thanks

Comment: It is updated automatically normally. So you should have a look at one of you inserted rows' primary keys. If not, you should reconfigure your TableAdapter because you might have added the `IDENTITY` after you've created the adapter. You can look at the column at the `AutoIncrement` property. That must be true.

Comment: the id is being incremented and added to db but how do i get the id from the newly inserted row

Comment: As i've told above: you just have to look at one of the inserted rows id column. It will be updated after the insert automatically if `AutoIncrement` is set to true (and it's actually auto-incremented in db).

Comment: thats what i need to know how do i know which is the newly inserted row

Comment: But you're the one who has added the row(s), aren't you?

Comment: yes...but I haven't defined the auto-incremented ID. Its generated automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last IDENTITY Insert "Using SCOPE_IDENTITY with CommandBuilder and DataAdapter"

In stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertCategory
  @CategoryName nvarchar(15),
  @Identity int OUT
AS
INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName) VALUES(@CategoryName)
SET @Identity = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

IN VB.net:

```
SqlParameter identParam = new SqlParameter("@Identity", SqlDbType.BigInt, 0, pKeyName);
identParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Please check out following links:

[Possible to retrieve IDENTITY column value on insert using SqlCommandBuilder (without using Stored Proc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136536/possible-to-retrieve-identity-column-value-on-insert-using-sqlcommandbuilder-wi)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/288850/Using-SCOPE_IDENTITY-with-CommandBuilder-and-DataA

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ks9f57t0(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2